# Rails where condition with timestamp

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have query, that would return me data depending on its created_at timestamp

my query looks like

```
condition[:created_at] = " > #{Time.now - 2.days}"

model.where(condition)
```

and this return me following sql

```
...WHERE `model`.`created_at` = ' > 2000-01-01T02:00:00+02:00'
```

so here timestamp looks different from what in db

So how do i pass correct timestamp to match `AR` format?

Comment: DateTime, not Time. If you want to use different operator than equality, you need to write it by hand `model.where('created_at > ?', DateTime.now - 2.days)`. Hash syntax only works for equalities.

Comment: @BroiSatse I had deleted my comment(as I can't edit now). I put it by mistake. I didn't notice the condition OP has.

Comment: well, its not good to add another where method just for this one condition, so i was looking for some way, to put it into the hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveSupport's `#ago` will help:

```
model.where("created_at > ?", 2.days.ago)
```

Also, I wrote a gem to contain common scopes for `created_at` queries and others: https://github.com/neighborland/scopy

Comment: had to go this way, since using hash didnt work at all